# capistrano, :db role, what's it for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

As far as I can tell, the capistrano `:db` role is used only to run migrations.

(Thus, in most cases it probably *shouldn't* actually be the server that runs your database. Why would you have a ruby/rails stack there (or allow ssh logins there)? it's just whatever server you want to actually execute the rails migrations).

And only the server identified as db role with `:primary => true` is used to run migrations.

So any other servers identified as 'db' role but without `:primary => true`... are used for nothing at all? So why does the default deploy.rb created by `capify .` encourage you to list them?  What would you even list here?

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Obviously, the name of role `:db` is misleading. As you pointed out, Capistrano defines it (with `:primary => true`) as a host that we execute `rake db:migrate` on, but database servers are not always running on such hosts. We can alter the schema of remote database server through a Rails app. The correct role name for this kind of host is not `:db`.

Inferring from the comments on [lib/capistrano/configuration/roles.rb](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/configuration/roles.rb), the original meaning of the role `:db` is a host on which database servers are running. We are expected to login to the `:db` hosts and do some tasks.

The designers of Capistrano should have defined `:migration` role or something else for the `deploy:migrate` task. But the association between the `:db` role with this task was defined six years ago with [9a6d2fb](https://github.com/halorgium/capistrano/commit/9a6d2fb7b65e963e73b0e14ee72361f0adb9db25) and has not been changed since then.

Generally speaking, the users of Capistrano can define roles and associate them with tasks freely. The `deploy:migrate` task is provided just as a *recipe* for Rails developers. Unfortunately, this recipe includes a misconception about how we do the database migration and is used widely for a long time.

Comment: You can now change the role name for migrations (which is also recommended): https://github.com/capistrano/rails#recommendations

Answer (score 4):

You may have a setup that includes a master database server and multiple slave servers. In some cases, you could have an capistrano task that needs to be run on all database servers. In others, you may want to run a task (for instance, a migration) only on the master server and allow the changes to propagate to the slave instances.

Comment: can you give any example of a task that would run on all database servers?  In this case, does this mean the actual hosts that the database itself is running on?

Comment: Yes. A single server CAN fulfill multiple roles, but it doesn't have to.  In many cases you can scale out your database with a single master and multiple slaves.  You might want to run a data migration on only the primary (master) server, but maybe if you have logging turned on for all database instances, you might want to hit all of them and archive the log files.