# Deploying rails app on separate app server and database server (both Linode)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, unicorn, linode

I'm having trouble deploying a basic rails app (which works on local machine, which works on heroku) to a distributed architecture (web server on one box, database server on another).

Here is my issue. It seems that Capistrano is not able to update the cached copy on my database server.

```
2013-05-12 11:32:57 executing `deploy:update_code'
updating the cached checkout on all servers
executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:morgs32/treebook.git master"
command finished in 1658ms
* executing multiple commands in parallel
-> "else" :: "if [ -d /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd  /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 73b5a632d417b3a6863d542b174b30077265bc7c && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b master git@github.com:morgs32/treebook.git /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 73b5a632d417b3a6863d542b174b30077265bc7c; fi"
-> "else" :: "if [ -d /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 73b5a632d417b3a6863d542b174b30077265bc7c && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b master git@github.com:morgs32/treebook.git /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 73b5a632d417b3a6863d542b174b30077265bc7c; fi"
servers: ["*app server ip*", "*database ip*"]
[*app server ip*] executing command
[*database ip*] executing command
** [*database ip* :: out] sh: 1: git: not found
command finished in 3072ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing multiple commands in parallel
-> "else" :: "rm -rf /home/morgan/apps/treebook/releases/20130512183302; true"
-> "else" :: "rm -rf /home/morgan/apps/treebook/releases/20130512183302; true"
servers: ["*app server ip*", "*database ip*"]
[*app server ip*] executing command
[*database ip*] executing command
command finished in 201ms
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 73b5a632d417b3a6863d542b174b30077265bc7c && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b master git@github.com:morgs32/treebook.git /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/morgan/apps/treebook/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 73b5a632d417b3a6863d542b174b30077265bc7c; fi'" on *database ip*
```

Of course wherever you see *app server ip*, or *database ip* I have the actual ips for those servers. Any ideas?

Comment: Your capistrano deployment probably doesnt need to talk to your database box, you can run the migrations from the rails app on the web server (as long as database.yml is set up correctly)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781767/capistrano-db-role-whats-it-for for more on db role

Comment: I think I tried this too early. First I'm going to make sure it works on a single box using capistrano, nginx, postgres and railscast #335. Once that works I'll tackle this one again (couple days). Thanks for suggestions so far.

Answer (score 1):

If the servers are located in the same data center, you can use the private IP addresses that are listed in the Linode Manager to communicate between the two servers without bandwidth costs. Depending on your operating system, you may have a software firewall that you need to open ports with to allow the communication.

Take a look at https://library.linode.com/remote-access#sph_adding-private-ip-addresses which has some more information about how to add the IP address if you don't have it setup already.